# too many values to unpack (expected 2) error

Tags: optimization, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters, particle-swarm

I am trying to optimize the hyperparameter of CNN using PSO, but cannot fix this error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)", not sure what I am missing in the fitness function:
main code:

## Define PSO optimization

```
dimensions = 3  # Number of hyperparameters to optimize
options = {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.3, 'w': 0.9}
lower_limit = np.array([1, 128, 512])
upper_limit = np.array([10, 256, 1024])
bounds = (lower_limit, upper_limit)
optimizer = GlobalBestPSO(n_particles=100, dimensions=dimensions, options=options, bounds=bounds)
best_hyperparameters, _ = optimizer.optimize(fitness_function, iters=20)
```

The details error for PSO part :

```
2023-07-06 19:09:25,049 - pyswarms.single.global_best - INFO - Optimize for 20 iters with {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.3, 'w': 0.9}
pyswarms.single.global_best:   0%|          |0/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2b66b04d1847> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 bounds = (lower_limit, upper_limit)
     10 optimizer = GlobalBestPSO(n_particles=100, dimensions=dimensions, options=options, bounds=bounds)
---> 11 best_hyperparameters, _ = optimizer.optimize(fitness_function, iters=20)

2 frames
<ipython-input-4-fecbe8b4fed7> in fitness_function(params)
      1 # Define the fitness function for PSO optimization
      2 def fitness_function(params):
----> 3     hidden_channels, kernel_size, stride = params
      4 
      5     # Set the device

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

at this line 6: `optimizer = GlobalBestPSO(n_particles=100, dimensions=dimensions, options=options, bounds=bounds)
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error, tried some solutions but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is arising because of the values you have put the `bounds` variables. As of the documentation, the `bounds` variable has to be a tuple with 2 values i.e `bounds=(lower_limit,upper_limit)` where your lower limits and upper limit are the numpy.ndarray or list of the ranges. So this version of the code works fine.

```
dimensions = 3  # Number of hyperparameters to optimize
options = {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.3, 'w': 0.9}
bounds = ([16,3,1],[64,7,3])  # Bounds for each hyperparameter
## The above line is which has been given in wrong format which causes error
optimizer=ps.single.GlobalBestPSO(n_particles=100, dimensions=dimensions, options=options,bounds=bounds)
best_hyperparameters,_ = optimizer.optimize(fitness_function, iters=20)
```

As you can see the shape of the bounds variable should be `(2,)` but as of your input it came out to be `(3,)`. So as a result of which you have got the `Error is this: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) at this line 6: optimizer = GlobalBestPSO(n_particles=100, dimensions=dimensions, options=options, bounds=bounds)`, as it expected to unpack 2 variables but you have given 3. 
 
P.S - You might be new to the community, but try to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it helps us to get the bug/query quite easily and it's quite representable. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Hi, I have tried your given solution and it still returns the similar error but now it is expecting 3!! 
'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)' 
Also, the error showing for this line of code now :
 'best_hyperparameters, _ = optimizer.optimize(fitness_function, iters=20)'

Comment: Can you share the new snippet of code you are writing and the error as an edit to your post. Try to include the whole error statement that arise, as of the bounds so that we will easier to understand the error properly.

Comment: If possible try to give the definition of the fitness_function that you have defined. As of the format of the `bounds` variable. it is correct as of the definition in the documentation of pyswarms. May be there is some issue in the function which you have defined

Comment: hi I have added the entire fitness function with as an answer, could not find a better way to add as a comment. Also edited my question and gave the enitre error statement for PSO. Sorry that I am totally dumb in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

Fitness function for PSO is as follows:

```
# Define the fitness function for PSO optimization
def fitness_function(params):
  hidden_channels, kernel_size, stride = params

# Set the device
  device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Create the CNN model
  model = CNN(input_channels=3, output_classes=10, hidden_channels=hidden_channels,
            kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride)
model.to(device)

# Define the loss function and optimizer
  criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
  optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Load the CIFAR10 dataset
  train_dataset = CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=ToTensor())
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

# Train the model
  num_epochs = 10
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

# Evaluate the model
  test_dataset = CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=ToTensor())
  test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

  model.eval()
  correct = 0
  total = 0
  with torch.no_grad():
    for images, labels in test_loader:
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

        outputs = model(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

  accuracy = correct / total
  return accuracy

    # Calculate the fitness value
  fitness = -accuracy
    # Return the fitness value and any additional information
  return fitness, accuracy
```